# ansible need to loop over multiple files

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible. I have a few directories and they all have different yml files in them. I want to write a task file which will load one YML file, use variables from it in the next task and keep repeating these steps for all YML files.

example:

- dir a - 10 yml files
- dir b - 8 yml files

I can not load all these file at once (some variables have different values for different file). I want to load one YML file at a time use it and then load another file. I tried using `block` but it seems looping is not possible in it. Any solution?

Comment: What is `dir a` and `dir b` - are they host variable folders? You could probably abuse `import_variables`, but it feels like there's an XY problem here

Comment: I suspect you are looking for `include_tasks`.

Comment: apologies for the late response.  to solve my issue, i wrote a shell script and call it during the run.

Comment: In respect to @Zeitounator 's answer you may find background information under [What's the difference between `include_tasks` and `import_tasks`?](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950).